# How to use "Flat Json"-Bootstrap 5 Table example with ejs + nodejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, html-table, ejs, bootstrap-5

I want to use the "Flat Json"-Bootstrap 5 Table example. [Link][1]

I am using expressjs with nodejs and ejs.
My Code so far:

````
```<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h2>JOB DASHBOARD</h2>

    
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-flat="true" data-search="true" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="" data-sortable="true">Order ID</th>
        <th data-field="" data-sortable="true">Liefertermin</th>
        <th data-field="" data-sortable="true">Fertigstellungstermin</th>
        <th data-field="" data-sortable="true">Keyline Nr</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% var count = 0; %>
    <% orders.forEach((order)=>{  %>
        <tr data-index="<%= count %>">
            <td><%= order.order_id %></td>
            <td><%= order.due_at %> </td>
            <td><%= order.deliver_at %> </td>
            <td><%= order.keyline_obj.event.data.attributes.reference %> </td>
        </tr>
        <% count +=1; %>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

I am loading the content from my mongoDB Database. The Variable "orders" is an array of order documents.
At the moment the data is loading but the searchfield doesnt appear at all and all the styling doesnt work although I have loaded the bootsrap css and js.
[1]: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html?bootstrap5#welcomes/flat-json.html

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that the is successfully sent but the respond is in json as the browser waiting

you can check data is received or not by => clicking right click on the screen =>press inspect => Network => click on the page file => then choose Response

you will find your html page with the updated data in it

- you can render it from your js script after fetching api like so

```js
await fetch(----your fetching code-----).then(res=>{
    document.open();
    res.text().then(function(text) {
    document.write(text)
        });
    })
```